# Derivative of cross product equation

Tags: vectors, differentiation

Recently I got a problem that equated the time derivative of a cross product d/dt (P x Q) with a function of time (like t + t^2).

Ex. d/dt (P x Q) = 5t - 6t^2

My question is, how can you have an equation with a cross product derivative (which is itself a vector) with a function of time?

Comment: If you quoted the actual problem, the situation might be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right. You can't sensibly equate a vector to a scalar. So the scalar function of $t$ on the right hand side of your equation can't be right. But you could have a vector function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product of two planar vectors is a scalar.

$$ \pmatrix{a \\ b} \times \pmatrix{x \\ y} = a y - b x $$

Also, note the following 2 planar cross products that exist between a vector and a scalar (out of plane vector).

$$ \pmatrix{a \\ b} \times \omega = \pmatrix{\omega\, b\\ -\omega\, a} $$

$$ \omega \times \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{-\omega\, y \\ \omega \, x} $$

All of the above are planar projections of the one 3D cross product.

Also note that the derivative is a linear operator which means the product rule applies

$$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} ( \vec{a} \times \vec{b} ) = ( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{a} ) \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times (\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{b}) $$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, are you implying that there is a way to actually solve the function?

Comment: @Chopin - that wasn't the question. The question is "My question is, how can you have an equation with a cross product derivative (which is itself a vector) with a function of time?"

Answer (score 0):

The vectors P and Q define a plane.  The cross product is perpendicular to that plane.  Your time function could describe the motion of an object in that perpendicular direction.

Comment: However, is there any way to actually solve such a function?

Comment: You would need the expressions (functions of time) represented by P and Q.